# Creating mbtiles using Maptiler for OpenMapTiles

Tags: maptiler, openmaptiles

I create a `mbfiles` file using MapTiler and loaded it into OpenMapTiles. The files that I have loaded are from earthexplorer.usgs.gov and composed of several .tif files.
Once I load the mbfiles into the server, I get the following message:

> WARNING
>
> OpenMapTiles Server is designed to work with data downloaded from
>   OpenMapTiles.com, the following files are unknown and will not be
>   used: file.mbtiles

Is there a document describing the advanced options I have to use in order to create a opem map tiles compatible mbtile files?

both products are from the same company

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, OpenMapTiles Server actually works only with data from OpenMapTilers.com. If you want to display data made in MapTiler Desktop on a map, you can upload it to the MapTiler Cloud service - https://www.maptiler.com/how-to/hosting-on-maptiler-cloud/

But what you wrote makes perfect sense: that's why we are working on MapTiler Server with an ability to serve MBTiles made by MapTiler Desktop/Engine. It is currently in pre-release status.

Comment: thank you for providing an answer, there is a npm mbtiles server module that works with openmaptilers.com provided mbtiles - I tested it with the free low res globe image, but it doesn't work with maptiler data. So my guess is that MapTiler output is not standard? I am looking into QGIS and tilemill to see if those can help me create mbtiles from GeoTiffs.

Comment: The output is standard raster MBTiles file. Right now, OpenMapTiles Server is capable to serve vector tiles only.

We are working on MapTiler Server with a capability of serving both vector and raster MBTiles AND MapTiler Desktop, which is able to render vector data.

Comment: so theoretically I can feed the output of MBTiles to a mbtiles server than supports png/jpg and that should work?

Comment: Yep, or wait for MapTiler Server (or contact us to become one of the early adaptors).

Comment: there are several of open source mbtile server implementations out there, what does MapTiler Server provide that is unique or better?

Comment: Easy-to-use (few clicks or two commands), number of provided services, an option to add base maps and easily customize them, can run behind a firewall or offline, ...